# React Native tensorflow image classification

Tags: react-native, tensorflow

I created a tfjs model with tensorflow, I want to use it in react native. I installed all the libraries according to the documentation. When it wants to load its model like this:

```
const modelJSON = require('./src/assets/model.json');
const modelWeights = require('./src/assets/group1-shard.bin');

  const loadModel = async (): Promise<void | tf.LayersModel> => {
    await tf.ready();
    const model = await tf
      .loadLayersModel(bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights))
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('[LOADING ERROR] info:', e);
      });
    return model;
  };
```

I get this error:

```
[LOADING ERROR] info: [Error: layer: Improper config format: {"node":[{"name":"image","op":"Placeholder","attr":{"shape":{"shape":{"dim":[{"size":"1"},{"size":"224"},{"size":"224"},{"size":"3"}]}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"mnas_v4_a_140_1/feature_network/feature_extractor/Mean/reduction_indices","op":"Const","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTINT32"},"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT32","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"2"}]}}}}},{"name":"mnas_v4_a_140/output/fc/tf_layer/kernel","op":"Const","attr":{"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTFLOAT","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"1280"},{"size":"899"}]}}},"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"}}},{"name":"mnas_v4_a_140/output/fc/tf_layer/bias","op":"Const","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTFLOAT","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"899"}]}}}}},{"name":"ExpandDims/dim","op":"Const","attr":{"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTINT32","tensorShape":{}}},"dtype":{"type":"DTINT32"}}},{"name":"mnas_v4_a_140_1/feature_network/stem/conv/Conv2D_weights","op":"Const","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"DTFLOAT"},"value":{"tensor":{"dtype":"DTFLOAT","tensorShape":{"dim":[{"size":"3"},{"size":"3"},{"size":"3"},{"size":"48"}]}}}}},{"name":"mnas_v4_a_140_1/feature_network/stem/conv/Conv2D_bn_offset","op":"Const","attr":{"dtype":{"type":"...
```

I can leave the model.json file empty and the error continues to be the same